# Windows: Write Directly To CD-R Sectors

Tags: windows, cd, sector

Are there any libraries or Windows API functions that enable writing to the sectors of a CD-R directly? I am able to read sectors from the drive using the ReadFile function provided by the Windows API but using the WriteFile function on the drive seems only to mark the disk as in-use (after executing a program in which WriteFile is used on a CD-R, I am unable to burn files onto the disk or eject it until I restart the system). When I restart the system, there is no data on the disk. Opening the disk drive for write access and calling the WriteFile function with the disk drive handle produces no system errors.

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know easy way, but there is a set of SCSI commands, that burning software use.

Under windows you has to get ASPI library to obtain **SendASPI32Command** [Free one](http://www.frogaspi.org/download.htm#frogaspi) and find somewhere a description of Multi-Media Commands. Start from www.t10.org, they sell it, but working draft can be found for free.

and then start [there](http://www.gentle.it/alvise/ASPI_1.HTM) and then look for example of MMC commands using in cdrecord sources.

It can be done but hard though.

Answer (score 0):

Access to the write process is probably restricted to allow compatibility with the drag-and-drop writing that can be done in the Explorer.

You could use an alternative approach and write to an ISO image and then dump that to the CD when it is complete.